# When saving in vscode it adds a self closing tag "/" automatically

Tags: html

When I save to vscode it adds a self closing tag "/" to my code automatically.
[before save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ1jR.png)
[after save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyPQv.png)

I am pretty sure it has to do with prettier settings. I am unsure how to resolve this. I am using chrome.

Comment: You can use `Auto Close Tag` extension.

Comment: every tag should have a closing tag so it is a good practice to close tags. img input br etc can be closed like this />

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @Anis suggested, it's good practice to have closing tags.
If you still want to remove it, press `ctrl+,`, and search for `html` in the search bar:
[image]

All that's left is to toggle the "HTML: Auto Closing Tags" checkbox off and restart vscode.